# Trying to understand balanceOf.call function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, blockchain, dapps

I am playing around with my ERC20 token. I created token on Rinkeby test network. I can't understand where I did a mistake. I am interacting with my token in truffle console.

After command

```
Token.deployed().then(function(instance){app = instance;})
```

I check my balance with command:

```
app.balanceOf.call("0xb9ac6f47A43d24F9D0d37049b7dbdC4EA0083d37")
```

And it works fine, I am getting the right answer.

Then I am trying to check my balance with commands:

```
app.balanceOf.call(accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]})
```

or

```
app.balanceOf.call(app.accounts[0], {from: app.accounts[0]})
```

or

```
app.balanceOf.call(address)
```

Where I did a mistake? How to call a function balanceOf ?

Information after command **app**:

```
 balanceOf:
  { [Function: bound ]
    request: [Function: bound ],
    call: [Function: bound ],
    sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
    estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
    getData: [Function: bound ],
    address: [Circular] },


....


 balanceOf:
  { [Function]
    call: [Function],
    sendTransaction: [Function],
    request: [Function: bound ],
    estimateGas: [Function] },
```

Comment: What is the error your getting... ? Update your qus.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`app.balanceOf(accounts[0])`

if you use `call` the function is evaluated locally (in the node you are connected) and the transaction is not sent to the network, therefore no need for `{from: accounts[0]}`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77218/discussion-on-answer-by-jaime-trying-to-understand-balanceof-call-function).

Comment: just for curious, would `app.balanceOf` be encoded as a `call` in the EVM bytecode?